# Adding Points to filled.contour in R - at the right place

Tags: r, plot

I'd like to add a point to an existing `filled.contour` plot, using the following code:

```
MyFunction <- function(x,y){
   return(dnorm(sqrt(x^2+y^2)))
}
wrapper <- function(x, y, my.fun, ...) {sapply(seq_along(x), FUN = function(i) my.fun(x[i], y[i], ...))}
meshstep <- 0.5
x<- seq(-20,20,meshstep)
y <-seq(-20,20,meshstep)
z <- outer(x,y,FUN = wrapper, my.fun=MyFunction)
filled.contour(x,y,z, col=rev(heat.colors(n=20, alpha=0.7)), nlevels=15)
points(0,0)
```

I'm pretty surprised that `points(0,0)` didn't put a point into the origin of the plot, but roughly located at x=10,y=0. Also, `locator()` seems to be prompting coordinates with respect to that 'new' coordinate system as well. Why is that?

Comment: This question has some overlap with the link provided by juba. Since I'm looking to make `locator()` work, I hope this merits not closing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option is to use the `plot.axes` argument as mentioned by @juba.  But, if you really need to add something after the plot has finished then you can use `locator` to click on 2 points in the plot where you know the values of the points in the coordinate system you want to use (opposite corners), then use the `updateusr` function from the TeachingDemos package to modify the current coordinate system to the one that you want to use.  You can then add to the plot using the new coordinate system (you may need to set `par(xpd=NA)`).

Answer (score 4):

You can find a detailed answer here :
[Plotting a box within filled.contour plots in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529212/plotting-a-box-within-filled-contour-plots-in-r)

In short, `filled.contour` use two different coordinates system, one for the filled contour and one for the legend. To solve your problem, you either have to use another function, or to put your `points` into the `plot.axes` argument :

```
filled.contour(x,y,z, col=rev(heat.colors(n=20, alpha=0.7)), nlevels=15,
               plot.axes={points(0,0)})
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have an idea how to make `locator()` work with `filled.contour`?

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible, given the two scales problem. Maybe you should try another function ?