# How I can add dots to a filled contour plot?

Tags: r, plot, contour

I used the volcano data (matrix) to plot a filled contour plot.

```
filled.contour(volcano, color.palette = terrain.colors, asp = 0.5)
```

Now I want to add a dot to the plot. The dot should show the highest point of the volcano. Is it possible to add a dot without using ggplot2? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

I thought you could just find the location of the maximum and add it using the `points()` function, but that doesn't work because the axis coordinates displayed in the plot are not the same as the internal coordinates the plot uses to place the plot elements (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529212/plotting-a-box-within-filled-contour-plots-in-r) for details).

Instead, you can use the `plot.axes` argument of `filled.contour` to get the maximum in the right place, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429350/adding-points-to-filled-contour-in-r-at-the-right-place). We also need to use the `axis` function to draw the axis ticks and labels, because the `plot.axes` argument overrides the default axes.

```
# Get coordinates of maximum
max.point = (which(volcano==max(volcano), arr.ind=TRUE) - 1)/(dim(volcano) - 1)

# Use plot.axes argument to plot maximum point
filled.contour(volcano, color.palette = terrain.colors, asp = 0.5,
               plot.axes={
                 points(max.point, col="red", pch=16)
                 axis(side=1)
                 axis(side=2)
                 }
               )
```

[image]

For reference, here's what happens when you try adding the point after the plot is created:

```
filled.contour(volcano, color.palette = terrain.colors, asp = 0.5)
points(max.point, col="red", pch=17)
```

[image]

Here's a ggplot2 version:

```
library(tidyverse)

cols = terrain.colors(3)

as.data.frame(t(volcano)) %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var="row") %>% 
  gather(col, value, -row) %>% 
  mutate(col=(as.numeric(gsub("V","",col)) - 1)/(nrow(volcano) - 1),
         row=(as.numeric(row) - 1)/(ncol(volcano) - 1)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(col, row, z=value)) +
    geom_raster(aes(fill=value)) +
    geom_contour(colour="grey50", size=0.2) +
    geom_point(data=. %>% filter(value==max(value)), 
               colour="red", shape=16, size=2) +
    coord_fixed(ratio = ncol(volcano)/nrow(volcano), expand=FALSE) +
    scale_fill_gradient2(low=cols[1], mid=cols[2], high=cols[3],
                         midpoint=mean(volcano)) +
    theme_minimal()
```

[image]